# searches by day month and year in groovy

Tags: list, groovy, date-parsing

I need to search for all orders with `shipDate` in October. It should show 1st and 2nd row.

CSV file example:

```
product_name, shipdate ,  arrivedate, prize
apple,   10/09/2017, 11/09/2017,  100
mango,  10/26/2017 ,11/09/2017,  200
pineapple, 12/10/2017, 12/20/2017,  200
```

Code which is working:

```
def reader = new StringReader('''product_name,shipdate,arrivedate,prize
apple,10/09/2017,11/09/2017,100
mango,10/26/2017,11/09/2017,200
pineapple,12/10/2017,12/20/2017,200  
''')

def headers=null
reader.splitEachLine(','){line->
    //remove spaces
    line=line.collect{it.trim()}
    if(headers==null){
        //convert headers array to [name:index] map
        headers = line.withIndex().collectEntries()
    }else{
        //print line only when you have a valid value in line
        if( line[ headers['product_name'] ]=='apple'){
            println line
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the following piece of code:

```
def input = '''product_name,shipdate,arrivedate,prize
apple,10/09/2017,11/09/2017,100
mango,10/26/2017,11/09/2017,200
pineapple,12/10/2017,12/20/2017,200  
'''

def lines = input.split('\n')[1..-1]        // skip headers
def data = lines.collect { it.split(',') }  // split row into list
def shippedInOctober = data.findAll { new Date().parse('MM/dd/yyyy', it[1]).month == 9 } // find particular data
```

You can use some 3rd party libs, like opencsv to parse the CSV file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following use of the `groovycsv` library (in this example, `data.csv` contains the data):

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.2')

import com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser

def file = "data.csv"
def text = new File(file).getText()
def data = CsvParser.parseCsv text

def results = []

data.each { def line ->
    def shippingDate = line.getAt(1).trim()

    // this could be more robust
    if (shippingDate ==~ /10.*/) {
        results << line.values.join(",")
    }
}

println "# results: "
results.each { println it }
```